# Getting HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: java, jsp, http

I am using Request.getScheme() to get the url from the request. It is comming HTTP instead of HTTPS into the request. As a result web page is blocking some content. and it is displaying a button show all content. Is there a way to convert the HTTP to the HTTPS that is present in the actual URL.

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: i am JAVA with Springs.

Comment: Just use replace("http","https");

Comment: Are you using some type of proxy? Which webcontainer are you using? Without this informations it is difficult to provide an answer...

Comment: We need more info about the web container (apache, jetty, ...) and some details about your https setup. The version number of your web container release can also help. The problem is that not all web containers support https the way they should, and that's why a lot of https setups are more like "workarounds". And you are probably experiencing the disadvantages/imperfections of your workaround. More recent releases of web containers are of course better equiped.